# How to use Regex Replace to conditionally remove blocks of text?

Tags: asp.net, regex

I would like to conditionally remove a block of text between specifed start and stop delimiters. The code below does not work, but hopefully it suggests enough of what I am trying to accomplish.

```
            If dr("ReferralPoints") > 0 Then
                Dim objRegex As Regex = New Regex("[HASNOVALUE:REFERRALPOINTS](.*)[/HASNOVALUE:REFERRALPOINTS]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase + RegexOptions.Singleline)
                Dim result As String = objRegex.Replace(strBody, "")
            End If
```

Answer (score 3):

The regular expression needs to be the following:

```
\[HASNOVALUE:REFERRALPOINTS](.*)\[/HASNOVALUE:REFERRALPOINTS]
```

You need to escape `[` here because it's a regex metacharacter.

In VB.NET, ([based on this quick reference sheet](http://www.harding.edu/fmccown/vbnet_csharp_comparison.html)), it looks like `\` is not an escape character, so you can simply write this as:

```
"\[HASNOVALUE:REFERRALPOINTS](.*)\[/HASNOVALUE:REFERRALPOINTS]"
```

#### See also

- [Regular expressions and escaping special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399078/regular-expressions-and-escaping-special-characters)

---

Also, in case you don't know, `(.*)` is greedy, and will take the longest match. You may need `(.*?)` instead, but this really depends on the problem definition.

```
---AxxZ----AxxZ----
   ^^^^^^^^^^^^
      A(.*)Z
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to escape the square brackets? In many other regex languages, square brackets create a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), meaning that the engine needs only find one of the characters within the brackets to call it a match.

If you escape the brackets, probably with a backslash `'\'`, that might be enough. I'll be the first to admit I'm not sure about ASP.NET specifically, though.

Comment: Ack, it might be two as per polygenelubricants' answer.

Comment: I'll be second to admit I have no idea how ASP.NET does it either =)

Comment: I believe it's only one backslash in vb.